# Why do I get an error while adding a foreign key constraint to a table?

Tags: sql, wordpress, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

Table wp_users wordpress have this syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_users` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_login` varchar(60) NOT NULL default '',
  `user_pass` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `user_nicename` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `user_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `user_url` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `user_registered` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `user_activation_key` varchar(60) NOT NULL default '',
  `user_status` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `display_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`),
  KEY `user_login_key` (`user_login`),
  KEY `user_nicename` (`user_nicename`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

And I wanted to integrate a system already implemented for wordpress but I'm having problems with foreign keys to connect the table wp_users.

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE attach (
  attach_id int unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,     
  email varchar(60) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (attach_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES wp_users(user_login_key) 
  ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)Engine=INNODB;
```

I wanted to connect to user_email from wp_users, but user_login and user_email will be the same.. And it's totally impossible to define attach_id as a FK to ID from wp_users, due to other situations in other tables.

When I submit gives error # 1005

Answer (score 2):

In your second create statement for the table `CREATE TABLE attach`, you have the foreign key reference like this

```
FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES wp_users(user_login_key)
```

In the above statement, the name **user_login_key** references to a constraint in the table `wp_users`. While creating foreign constraints, you need to reference a field name in another table that you would like to create the relation and not the constraint name. Change the reference statement in the *CREATE TABLE attach* as following to fix the issue. In this statement **user_login** refers to the column of the same name

```
FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES wp_users(user_login)
```

[**Click here to view that both tables are created successfully in SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f601a)

*Script*:

```
    CREATE TABLE attach 
(
        attach_id   int unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment
    ,   email varchar(60) NOT NULL default ''
    ,   PRIMARY KEY  (attach_id)
    ,   FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES wp_users(user_login) 
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)Engine=INNODB;
```

Answer (score 1):

PLEASE CHECK YOUR  PARENT AND CHILD COLUMN DATA TYPES MUST BE SAME OR NOT?

For Example:

in your parent table have column like

```
  Fb_user_id INT(4) NOT NULL,
```

in your child table also u must give the same data type like
      ID INT(4) NOT NULL,

don't add any extra attributes like 
            unsigned
 like that.